# Android Proguard Kotlinx Coroutines warning

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, kotlin-coroutines

I have these warnings? How to solve it?

I tried to do `-dontwarn kotlinx.coroutines.flow.**inlined**`
It solves the warning, but I think my app crashes.

> Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$10$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object collect$$forInline(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowCollector,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$10
>   Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$2$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object collect$$forInline(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowCollector,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$2
>   Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$3$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object collect$$forInline(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowCollector,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$3
>   Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$4$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object collect$$forInline(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowCollector,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$4
>   Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$5$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object collect$$forInline(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowCollector,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$5
>   Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$6$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object collect$$forInline(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowCollector,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$6
>   Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$7$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object collect$$forInline(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowCollector,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$7

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

`-dontwarn` does what it says. This might rather be something alike:

```
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.**
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated from `kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.2` to `:1.3.7`, at which point all of those warnings went away.

I did get a few new ones, and needed to add the following to remove them:

`-dontwarn kotlinx.coroutines.debug.**`